# Read the Windows Phone device memory like SD card etc

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I would like to build application like File Explorer that will work on Windows Phone 8.

How to get access programmatically to device memory?

I know there is a class ExternalStorage which will allow me to read from SD card, but what about device memory (internal)?

Comment: this might help.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681698(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Note: any files stored in app storage will not be accessible. The Microsoft Files app already provides the functionality you mentioned.